# Does hadoop auto-copy input files not on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

Using hadoop streaming:

```
hadoop jar hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar -file mapper.rb -mapper mapper.rb -file reducer.rb -reducer reducer.rb -input textfile.txt -output output
```

Assuming the directory I am in is "/home/user/sei/Documents" and the textfile.txt

```
1) is in the same folder as the directory I am currently in 
2) I did not use -copyFromLocal to put textfile.txt into HDFS
```

Does hadoop automatically copy the input files (in this case textfile.txt) to some location on HDFS (i.e. "/user/sei/textfile.txt" automatically upon execution) to use for processing? Does this apply to all cases of hadoop commands (i.e. hadoop jar jarfile **myfilename**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not copy the records into HDFS, that you will have to do by yourself. If you are running a single node, or a pseudo distributed cluster on one machine you should be ok with a local file path.  But if you are running a distributed cluster, the mappers and reducers will not be able to find that file.

Comment: If I am running a single node, why is it that the one machine/single node cluster is okay with a local file path? I thought the whole point of having HDFS was that hadoop needs all files needed to be on HDFS? Shouldnt hadoop not be able to find the file since the data is local on NFS?

Comment: If its a local file, its still accessible to that node, just not other nodes.  For HDFS itself, Hadoop Distributed File System, files inside there are accessible to all nodes on the cluster. The main point of HDFS is replication, distributed accessibility, and some others, but its not necessary for hadoop to run on a single machine.

Comment: Most enlightening, greedybuddha.